# Not random sample of permutations of a set of lists

Tags: python, permutation

I have a set of lists and a list with *all permutations* of the set of lists.

```
mylist = []
mylist.append(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
mylist.append(['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'])
mylist.append(['f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'])
# Print all permutations
print(list(itertools.product(*mylist)))
```

**Output**

```
[('a', '1', 'f'), ('a', '1', 'g'), ('a', '1', 'h'), ('a', '1', 'i'), ('a', '1', 'j'), ('a', '2', 'f'), ('a', '2', 'g'), ('a', '2', 'h'), ('a', '2', 'i'), ('a', '2', 'j'), ('a', '3', 'f'), ('a', '3', 'g'), ('a', '3', 'h'), ('a', '3', 'i'), ('a', '3', 'j'), ('a', '4', 'f'), ('a', '4', 'g'), ('a', '4', 'h'), ('a', '4', 'i'), ('a', '4', 'j'), ('a', '5', 'f'), ('a', '5', 'g'), ('a', '5', 'h'), ('a', '5', 'i'), ('a', '5', 'j'), ('b', '1', 'f'), ('b', '1', 'g'), ('b', '1', 'h'), ('b', '1', 'i'), ('b', '1', 'j'), ('b', '2', 'f'), ('b', '2', 'g'), ('b', '2', 'h'), ('b', '2', 'i'), ('b', '2', 'j'), ('b', '3', 'f'), ('b', '3', 'g'), ('b', '3', 'h'), ('b', '3', 'i'), ('b', '3', 'j'), ('b', '4', 'f'), ('b', '4', 'g'), ('b', '4', 'h'), ('b', '4', 'i'), ('b', '4', 'j'), ('b', '5', 'f'), ('b', '5', 'g'), ('b', '5', 'h'), ('b', '5', 'i'), ('b', '5', 'j'), ('c', '1', 'f'), ('c', '1', 'g'), ('c', '1', 'h'), ('c', '1', 'i'), ('c', '1', 'j'), ('c', '2', 'f'), ('c', '2', 'g'), ('c', '2', 'h'), ('c', '2', 'i'), ('c', '2', 'j'), ('c', '3', 'f'), ('c', '3', 'g'), ('c', '3', 'h'), ('c', '3', 'i'), ('c', '3', 'j'), ('c', '4', 'f'), ('c', '4', 'g'), ('c', '4', 'h'), ('c', '4', 'i'), ('c', '4', 'j'), ('c', '5', 'f'), ('c', '5', 'g'), ('c', '5', 'h'), ('c', '5', 'i'), ('c', '5', 'j'), ('d', '1', 'f'), ('d', '1', 'g'), ('d', '1', 'h'), ('d', '1', 'i'), ('d', '1', 'j'), ('d', '2', 'f'), ('d', '2', 'g'), ('d', '2', 'h'), ('d', '2', 'i'), ('d', '2', 'j'), ('d', '3', 'f'), ('d', '3', 'g'), ('d', '3', 'h'), ('d', '3', 'i'), ('d', '3', 'j'), ('d', '4', 'f'), ('d', '4', 'g'), ('d', '4', 'h'), ('d', '4', 'i'), ('d', '4', 'j'), ('d', '5', 'f'), ('d', '5', 'g'), ('d', '5', 'h'), ('d', '5', 'i'), ('d', '5', 'j'), ('e', '1', 'f'), ('e', '1', 'g'), ('e', '1', 'h'), ('e', '1', 'i'), ('e', '1', 'j'), ('e', '2', 'f'), ('e', '2', 'g'), ('e', '2', 'h'), ('e', '2', 'i'), ('e', '2', 'j'), ('e', '3', 'f'), ('e', '3', 'g'), ('e', '3', 'h'), ('e', '3', 'i'), ('e', '3', 'j'), ('e', '4', 'f'), ('e', '4', 'g'), ('e', '4', 'h'), ('e', '4', 'i'), ('e', '4', 'j'), ('e', '5', 'f'), ('e', '5', 'g'), ('e', '5', 'h'), ('e', '5', 'i'), ('e', '5', 'j')]
```

From above list I want to extract **10 items** under the following conditions:

- The *a* should appear 6 times, the *b* 3 times and the *c* 1 time.
- The *5* should appear 5 times (the rest is random)
- The *f* should appear 2 times and the *i* should appear 4 times (the rest is random)

Comment: Why don't you repeatedly take one item from the list until you have 10 items that satisfy all conditions?

Comment: Or: why don't you generate all possible 10-item subsets of the list and take the first one that satisfies all conditions?

Comment: All you need is to write a generator function which will take lists as args, iterate over product of those lists and yield elements which satisfy provided conditions.

Comment: What is the larger purpose/context here? If your entire problem is of exactly this form (the same number of a's, 5's etc) for the exact same list, a solution isn't too hard to find by brute force. Are you trying to generalize this to larger lists and generic constraints of this form? If so, a SAT solver approach starts being promising.

Comment: Btw, those conditions don't allow you to pick element randomly based only on a single condition. E.g. final list should contain element `('a', 5, ?)` and simple bruteforce algorithm will easily fail satisfying this. Probably, you should add some information about how you want to apply this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your list of *permutations* actually contains only combinations. To impose frequencies to your selection of 10, you can pre-fill parts of the combinations with the required values and complete the rest with random values from the remaining elements of the corresponding list.  Then shuffle the parts before assembling then into the 10 combinations items:

```
from random import choices,sample 
part0 = sample(['a']*6 + ['b']*3 + choices("cde",k=1)  ,10)
part1 = sample(['5']*5           + choices("1234",k=5) ,10)
part2 = sample(['f']*2 + ['i']*4 + choices("ghj",k=4)  ,10)
result = list(zip(part0,part1,part2))
```

Output:

```
print(*result,sep="\n")
('a', '5', 'i')
('a', '3', 'j')
('b', '5', 'i')
('a', '4', 'g')
('b', '5', 'h')
('b', '5', 'g')
('a', '4', 'f')
('a', '3', 'i')
('a', '1', 'i')
('d', '5', 'f')
  \    \    \____ 4 times 'i', 2 times 'f'
   \    \________ 5 times '5'
    \____________ 6 times 'a', 3 times 'b'
```

Note that this may produce duplicate combinations.  To work around that, you can place the 4 lines in a loop that regenerates the combinations until they are all distinct (with your conditions and a selection of 10 this results in 3.75 attempts on average):

For example:

```
result = set()
while len(result) != 10: 
    part0 = sample(['a']*6 + ['b']*3 + choices("cde",k=1) ,10)
    part1 = sample(['5']*5 + choices("1234",k=5) ,10)
    part2 = sample(['f']*2 + ['i']*4 + choices("ghj",k=4) ,10)
    result = set(zip(part0,part1,part2))
```

If you really want permutations, then you can randomize the position of items produced by zip:

```
...
result = set(map(lambda c:tuple(sample(c,3)),zip(part0,part1,part2)))
```

which will then give actual permutations in the result (becoming less likely to have duplicates and only needs 1.22 attempts on average):

```
('5', 'b', 'i')
('2', 'j', 'a')
('b', 'j', '5')
('g', '2', 'a')
('2', 'f', 'a')
('i', '5', 'a')
('g', '5', 'b')
('i', '1', 'a')
('d', '5', 'f')
('i', '4', 'a')
```

Comment: Yes, you got it: I said permutations but I meant combinations.